# Python inserting backslashes during regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to do a regex to substitute in a backslash, but Python seems to be inserting a double-backslash, and I can't make it stop!

```
>>> re.sub('a', '\\ b', 'a')
'\\ b'
```

Double backslash is supposed to be backslash (escape + backslash = backslash), but it ends up being literal.

If I remove the double slash, it doesn't print one at all:

```
>>> re.sub('a', '\ b', 'b')
'b'
```

How do I get Python to sub in just *one* backslash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not inserting a double backslash. That is simply the interactive interpreter showing the string as a string literal. Use `print` to see the actual string:

```
>>> "\\n"
'\\n'
>>> print "\\n"
\n
```

Comment: Yes, you're right! Unfortunately, this oddity is causing my nose doctests to fail, as I have a doctest embedded, and the doctest interpreter gets the \\ back. How do I get the interpreter to stop being silly?

Comment: You don't.  Either use `print` in the doctest, or use `'\\'`.  the whole "point" of doctests is to look the same as interactive use.  Say... are you using a raw string in that doctest?  You should be!

Comment: Don't forget that the docstring is itself a string, so it will undergo one level of "unescaping" before being run as a doctest.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose this isn't an *answer* (I second Liquid_Fire), but a suggestion:

```
"\\b" -> \b
r"\b" -> \b
```

Use r"" raw strings to simplify backslashes in Python.

Comment: Never mind... I'll upvote yours because someone downvoted mine.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the string with the letter "r".  This instructs Python to interpret the string literally.

For your code:

`re.sub('a', r'\ b', 'a')`

You will often find "r" used with Python and regular expressions.